# Google Sheets' QUERY multiple sheets and return unique values

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I need to query two sheets and return all columns and unique values which match specific criteria.

I've used this but it doesn't work:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,Sheet2!A:D, "select * where B=0"))
```

My shared sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ysuvyBHU21uXv_DxzBJwC7tMnGPyaqFqab7m1d-vwyo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({Sheet1!A:D; Sheet2!A:D}, "where Col2=0"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 Sheet1!A:D, {"Name"; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦Comp1", ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)-1), "♦"))}; 
 Sheet2!A:D,          TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦Comp2", ROWS(Sheet2!A:A)),   "♦"))}, 
 "where Col2=0"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that it could add an extra column (E) which would output the value of cell C1. See my shared sheet example.

Comment: I added a third sheet and duplicated the last line of the formula but get an error. How do i change the formula to include other sheets?

Comment: `=UNIQUE(QUERY({
Sheet1!A:D, {"Name"; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦Comp1", ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)-1), "♦"))}; 
Sheet2!A:D, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦Comp2", ROWS(Sheet2!A:A)), "♦")); 
Sheet3!A:D, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦Comp3", ROWS(Sheet3!A:A)), "♦"))}, 
"where Col2=0"))`

Comment: Any idea why it errors when querying lots of data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-9eVHrVwhZt7r1gD8-J4vV6UUckhunnRlOJuULDkKc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @chappers link/sheet is private - pls share it so I could see it

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY({
forbes!A:D, {"Outranking Domain"; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦♂", ROWS(forbes!A:A)-1), "♦"))}; 
roebuckslaw!A:D,                  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦♀", ROWS(roebuckslaw!A:A)), "♦"));
blakewater!A:D,                   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦♫", ROWS(blakewater!A:A)), "♦"));  
watsonramsbottom!A:D,             TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦♪", ROWS(watsonramsbottom!A:A)), "♦"))}, 
"where Col2>Col3 and Col3>0 order by Col4 Desc label Col3 'Competitor'"),"♂","forbes"),"♀","roebuckslaw"),"♫","blakewater"),"♪","watsonramsbottom"))`